# Realizing different column formats with numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy, save

I want to create a `.csv` file using `numpy.savetxt`. Each `row` of the file indicates a certain event. Every row has multiple `columns` indicating different elements of the event. The information stored in each `column` is different. Certain `columns` will contain single `float` values while others should contain two `floats` that are connected to each other. If I would call that column when loading the `.csv` I should obtain the two `float` values.

I have the following code:

```
import numpy

rows = 5
columns = 2 
save_values = numpy.zeros((rows, columns))

for idx in xrange(rows):
  column_0 = float(idx)
  column_1 = [idx + 5., idx + 15.]

  save_values[idx, :] = column_0, column_1

numpy.savetxt("outfile.csv", save_values, delimiter = ",")
```

This however results in the following error message:

```
  save_values[idx, :] = column_0, column_1
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

which is understandable. However, despite knowing why it is going wrong I am having a hard time realizing my goal.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: In a numpy array, all elements must have the same type, i.e. you can not have the first column be a number, and the second column be a vector in a numpy array. You need pandas table for that.

Comment: You can, however, have a [structured numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) where the fields have different dtypes.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't even getting to the `savetxt` step.

```
save_values[idx, :] = column_0, column_1
```

the target is 2 values (2 columns).  The source is `idx` and a list.

That's why it's giving you the 'setting with a sequence' error.  It can't put the list in `save_values[idx,1]`.

You could define a `save_values` array that has 2 fields, and one of the fields having 2 elements.  But how would you save it?

How should the text file appear - 3 columns separated by `,`?  or two columns with special structure inside the 2nd?, e.g.

```
 1.2, 3.5, 4.2   # or
 1.2, [2.5, 4.2]
```

That in turn raises the issue of what can be loaded.  `genfromtxt` can handle the 3 columns; it can't readily hand the nested columns.  As a default `genfromtxt` would read the 3 column case as 3 columns, but it is possible to give it the 2 fields `dtype`.

Anyways, for saving I think generating 3 columns is simplest.  Reloading could be done with columns or fields.

I can generate a compound dtype array with:

```
In [329]: dt = np.dtype('i,(2,)f')
In [330]: dt
Out[330]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [331]: save_values = np.zeros((5,),dtype=dt)
In [332]: for i in range(5):
     ...:     save_values[i]=(i,(i+5., i+15.))
     ...:     
In [333]: save_values
Out[333]: 
array([(0, [5.0, 15.0]), (1, [6.0, 16.0]), (2, [7.0, 17.0]),
       (3, [8.0, 18.0]), (4, [9.0, 19.0])], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
```

But if I try to save it I get an error

```
In [334]: np.savetxt('test.txt',save_values,delimiter=',')
...
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))]') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e')
```

I can save it by spelling out the write format, `fmt%tuple(save_values[0])`, but that puts `[]` in the output:

```
In [335]: np.savetxt('test.txt',save_values,fmt='%10d, %s')
In [336]: cat test.txt
         0, [  5.  15.]
         1, [  6.  16.]
         2, [  7.  17.]
         3, [  8.  18.]
         4, [  9.  19.]
```

I can flatten the array dtype with a view (here I'm keeping the 1st field integer just to keep things interesting):

```
In [337]: dt1=np.dtype('i,f,f')
In [338]: save_values.view(dt1)
Out[338]: 
array([(0, 5.0, 15.0), (1, 6.0, 16.0), (2, 7.0, 17.0), (3, 8.0, 18.0),
       (4, 9.0, 19.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

Now I can save it as 3 columns:

```
In [340]: np.savetxt('test.txt',save_values.view(dt1),fmt='%10d, %10f, %10f')
In [341]: cat test.txt
         0,   5.000000,  15.000000
         1,   6.000000,  16.000000
         2,   7.000000,  17.000000
         3,   8.000000,  18.000000
         4,   9.000000,  19.000000
```

and I can reload it with either dtype:

```
In [342]: np.genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=dt)
Out[342]: 
array([(0, [5.0, 15.0]), (1, [6.0, 16.0]), (2, [7.0, 17.0]),
       (3, [8.0, 18.0]), (4, [9.0, 19.0])], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])

In [343]: np.genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=dt1)
Out[343]: 
array([(0, 5.0, 15.0), (1, 6.0, 16.0), (2, 7.0, 17.0), (3, 8.0, 18.0),
       (4, 9.0, 19.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

I could have also created the `text.txt` with a 5x3 array of floats.

The key point with `savetxt` is that it iterates over the rows your array, formats them, and writes that line to the file.  So your array has to work with:

```
for row in myarray:
   print(fmt % tuple(row))
```

`fmt` may be be spelled out, or may build from a single field format, eg.

```
fmt = ','.join(['%10f']*3)   # or
fmt = '%10d, %10f, %10f'
```

So it comes down to standard Python string formatting.